# PhpStorm - How to remove keywords being highlighted in JS documentation?

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, webstorm

I am trying to figure out how to remove keywords in my JS documentation from being highlighted, but I am having no luck.

[image]

Comment: `/**` denotes JSDoc.. The IDE can have special handling to improve readability for certain elements (e.g. code samples). Definitely try `/*`

Comment: This might be coming from the **Material Theme UI plugin** -- try disabling `Language additions` in plugin settings if you have it enabled -- any difference? If yes -- it has  been fixed on early August (https://github.com/ChrisRM/material-theme-jetbrains/issues/1814) -- try upgrading that plugin.

Comment: Sorry guys...I meant documentation, not comment

Comment: The question still stands. How so I remove the highlighting from the jsDoc? This seems to have changed at some point in one of the updates.

Comment: Accordingly to your screenshot the keywords are highlighted in JSDoc comments, right?

Comment: Please try disabling all custom plugins at Settings | Plugins > click on a gear icon > "Disable All Downloaded Plugins", restart IDE and check the issue after that.

Comment: @LazyOne yes. I checked the settings and there are no settings for keywords.

Comment: As @LazyOne mentioned above, it must be the issue with Material Theme UI plugin, the IDE itself doesn't highlight comments this way

Comment: @DavidLabbe **1)** `Material Theme UI plugin` (if you have it installed) -- disable that plugin, restart the IDE and check again -- does the issue persists? **2)** If #1 helped -- try updating that plugin to the latest version. If you cannot or already on the latest version -- check if you have **Language additions** option enabled in that plugin settings (`Material Theme Settings > Other Tweaks` tab).

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks for your help. It was the Material Theme plugin and the Language additions option. I tried this the other day, but I guess I never restarted Phpstorm for it to fully take effect. I have the latest version.
Thanks again for everyones help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly to your screenshot the keywords are highlighted in JSDoc comments (`/**` denotes JSDoc while `/*` is just  plain multiline comment).

The IDE *can have* special handling to improve readability for certain elements in Doc comments (e.g. code samples etc)... but in this case it has no such highlighting for keywords. So this has to be coming from a 3rd party plugin.

1. *Material Theme UI plugin* (if you have it installed): please disable that plugin (`Settings/Preferences | Plugins`), restart the IDE and check again -- does the issue persists?
2. If that helped then we clearly have identified what plugin is causing this. Enable that plugin back and restart the IDE.
3. Now check if you have **Language additions** option enabled in that plugin settings (`Material Theme Settings > Other Tweaks` tab). Please disabled that option.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Honestly, though I would just skip to step 3 from above (uncheck Language additions ) and as I found out you need to restart the IDE after.

Answer (score 0):

In the standard settings it is not highlighted. I don't know if you changed something but i can't recreate it...

Maybe just remove the second "*" on line 1?

```
    /*

in, false , true, const
 */
```

Comment: Could be right. I guess /** start a documentation not a comment in PHPStorm so removing the second * might help

Comment: Sorry guys...I meant documentation, not comment